# Citing PostGIS in formal publications?

Tags: postgis

I have worked on a piece of academic work using the PostGIS extension on PostgreSQL (pgadmin). I have done a lot of work including buffer generation and data processing.

How do I cite this software for publication purposes?

For example the r software R (R Core Team, 2015)

R Core Team, 2015. R: a language and environment for statistical computing. In: Team
RDC (Ed.), R Foundation for Statistical Computing. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria.

Comment: this tends to be something only academic dev teams care about, if it isn't clearly marked on the project home page, just mention which version you are using and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one paper that cited the software. Within the content, the author wrote:

> we use the open source database PostgreSQL with the GIS extensions of
>   PostGIS and pgRouting.

Under the bibliography section, the author listed as below:

```
                      pgRouting, pgRouting; http://pgrouting.org/.

                      PostGIS,PostGIS; http://postgis.net/.

                      PostreSQL,PostgreSQL; http://www.postgresql.org/.
```

Finally, if anyone wants to have a look at that paper, the paper link is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0269749116305280?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 0):

Seems a (somewhat) popular way of citing PostGIS is the following:

```
@misc{postgis2018postgis,
  title={PostGIS, spatial and geographic objects for postgreSQL},
  author={PostGIS Project Steering Committee and others},
  year={2018},
  url={https://postgis.net}
}
```

> PostGIS Project Steering Committee, 2018. PostGIS, spatial and geographic objects for postgreSQL.